# Install yarn in a docker container says missing dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, yarnpkg

I'm using the node:6.7.0 image as my docker container and then follow the installation guide for yarn

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv D101F7899D41F3C3
echo "deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

Then I do

```
apt-get update && apt-get install yarn
```

But at this point I get an error message which says

```
yarn : Depends: nodejs (>= 4.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

I've echoed `node -v` before the install and it also says `6.7.0`

Anything that I'm missing?

Comment: It might be that the `node:6.7.0` container doesn't use APT to install Node because the APT-provided `nodejs` package is too old. You could try to run `npm install -g yarn` instead of installed `yarn` through APT.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) is right - if you check the [Dockerfile for Node](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/f3c3821591765ad0727bdde2cb98f41dc1b9b4b9/6.8/Dockerfile) you'll see they install Node by downloading the TAR, not through APT. You can check this by running an interactive container:

```
> docker run -it node:6.7.0 bash
root@465fa07437c9:/# dpkg -s nodejs
dpkg-query: package 'nodejs' is not installed and no information is available
```

You can use NPM in your Dockerfile instead:

```
FROM node:6.7.0
RUN npm install -g yarn
```

Comment: This is working, I already tried this like suggested in the comment. Thank you anyway

Comment: This should be fixed by https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/916, which changes the nodejs dependency from "depends" to "recommends" to allow usage of Node.js when it's not installed through apt-get.